# Is it possible to isolate Docker container from Visual Studio solution files in an Asp.net core project?

Tags: visual-studio, docker, asp.net-core, dockerfile

I created an Asp.net Core project with VS2017 and I chose to active Docker debugging.

In this application, I want to create some files in _env.ContentRootPath or _env.WebRootPath (i don't know which one is better).

When I do this, the file is correctly created on the Docker container, but it also appears in my host storage and so in the VS solution tree. It seems like the container folder is mapped to my host solution folder.

Shouldn't the container be isolated from my host? Is there a way to avoid this behavior?

Here is the Dockerfile content:

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-aspnetcore-runtime AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 53665
EXPOSE 44371

FROM microsoft/dotnet:2.1-sdk AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY MyProject/MyProject.csproj MyProject/
RUN dotnet restore MyProject/MyProject.csproj
COPY . .
WORKDIR /src/MyProject
RUN dotnet build MyProject.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish MyProject.csproj -c Release -o /app

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MyProject.dll"]
```

Comment: This is by design, when you **DEBUG** your application. Then your local solution folder will be linked as volume within the container. iirc this is required, so that Visual Studio can attach to the process that runs inside the container as well as to reduce debug time (otherwise the container needs to be built on every debug session) and save space on the HDD by creating new containers on every debug session. If you don't want that you should publish or run the container in release mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the [Debug Docker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/host-and-deploy/docker/visual-studio-tools-for-docker?view=aspnetcore-2.1#debug) docs as this is the designed behavior:

> The dev image lacks the app contents, as Debug configurations use volume mounting to provide the iterative experience. To push an image, use the Release configuration.

Your only way is to run in Release mode, as this will create a new Docker image.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that answer. So maybe it is not a good practice to create files in _env.ContentRootPath or _env.WebRootPath? Is there a predefined folder I can use to create runtime generated files that are not automatically added to the solution?

Comment: If its good practice or not depends. Whatever you put in the `wwwroot` folder will be publicly accessible via Web (assuming you have activated the `.UseStaticFiles` middleware and not change the folder from where it serves from). Can be perfectly fine in one case and fatal in other

Comment: Those are private files that are useful only for the app (in my case, they are some config files retrieved from a database). So I'll try to avoid WebRootPath ;).